# submission object is updated on navigating to another page in formio

Tags: reactjs, formio

I have integrated the formio in react application and created a form with multiple pages. On viewing and filling the first page response, I am calling API to save the submission using API call on moving the next page (Custom button added as 'Next'). But, submission is not persist whenever page is changing and it is updated with the fields available on current page being rendered.

How should I persist the previous page submission?

I have stored the submission using useState and updating the state for submission on response of API, but it is being updated as soon page changes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.